# Is there a way to automatically map jOOQ records to Java records?

Tags: java, jooq

For this example, I am using the [Sakila Sample Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/).

Let's say I have a `Film` record as follows:

```
public record Film(UShort filmId, String title) {
}
```

If I am reading films from jOOQ, I can easily map them to `Film` using the following:

```
List<Film> films = this.context.select(Tables.FILM.FILM_ID, Tables.FILM.TITLE)
                               .from(Tables.FILM)
                               .limit(10)
                               .fetch(Records.mapping(Film::new));
```

Now let's say I want each film and the actors associated with it. For this, I decide to use `multiset`:

```
Set<SelectField<?>> readFields = Set.of(
    Tables.FILM.FILM_ID,
    Tables.FILM.TITLE,
    DSL.multiset(
        DSL.select(Tables.FILM_ACTOR.actor().FIRST_NAME, Tables.FILM_ACTOR.actor().LAST_NAME)
           .from(Tables.FILM_ACTOR)
           .where(Tables.FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID.eq(Tables.FILM.FILM_ID))
        )
       .as("actors")
);

var result = this.context.select(readFields)
                         .from(Tables.FILM)
                         .limit(10)
                         .fetch();
```

Now that I have my results, I want to map them into a record `FilmActors`:

```
public record FilmActors(UShort filmId, String title, List<Actor> actors) {
    public record Actor(String firstName, String lastName) {
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do this automatically, or with the help of a library like ModelMapper? I'm wanting to avoid rolling a custom `RecordMapper` if possible. Thanks!

I tried using jOOQ's built-in `Records` class, and tried to see if ModelMapper supports records.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? The documented ad-hoc conversion utilities aren't what you're looking for? Why?

Comment: @LukasEder I guess I'm looking for something like `org.jooq.Records`, but for nested records like `FilmActors`. Not sure if there is an easier way to obtain that other than writing my own `RecordMapper`. It looks like ModelMapper is still waiting on Java records support

Answer (score 2):

I think found an answer [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) under *Using ad hoc converters on nested collections*. `convertFrom` did the trick:

```
Field<List<FilmActors.Actor>> actors = DSL.multiset(
                                              DSL.select(Tables.FILM_ACTOR.actor().FIRST_NAME, Tables.FILM_ACTOR.actor().LAST_NAME)
                                                 .from(Tables.FILM_ACTOR)
                                                 .where(Tables.FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID.eq(Tables.FILM.FILM_ID))
                                          )
                                          .as("actors")
                                          .convertFrom(record -> record.map(Records.mapping(FilmActors.Actor::new)));

List<FilmActors> filmActors = this.context.select(Tables.FILM.FILM_ID, Tables.FILM.TITLE, actors)
                                          .from(Tables.FILM)
                                          .limit(10)
                                          .fetch(Records.mapping(FilmActors::new));
```

Comment: @LukasEder Is this the approach you would suggest? Also, any recommendations for indentation in IntelliJ? It does not seem to like jOOQ and multiset haha

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind when I said *ad-hoc conversion utilities*

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks! Just discovered those.